# Creating a Macro in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, macros, teradata

I created a macro in Teradata SQL (my first time doing this). I've used SAS for macros in the past so that's where my background is. But for this project I need to use Teradata and a macro would really help.

```
CREATE MACRO member_count(state CHAR(2)) AS
(
  Select
    ':state1' as state,
     other_vars, etc
  FROM database.:state_member;
);

EXEC member_count(NM);
```

What I would assume to happen here is that any time the phrase ':state' is used that will invoke the letters NM into the code. However, when I run the code I get the error 3707: Syntax error, expected something like an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between '.' and ':'.

Is a macro possible for what I want to accomplish? If so, what do I need to change?

Comment: Pretty sure that you cannot use a variable/parameter as a table or column name (`database.:state_member`). You're trying to use dynamic SQL, which macros don't support.  You would need to use a stored proc for this.

Comment: You can't use a variable for an object name here (a table in this instance, but also a database, a column, etc). You'll have to switch over to using a Stored Procedure and you will have to set your dynamically generated SQL to a varchar variable, then you will have to open a cursor generated from that dynamic sql so that it can be returned to the user calling the procedure.

Comment: before creating macro or teradata procedure, please check whether you have permission to create one. I have not seen anywhere I have worked to have permission to create Teradata SP or macro for a SAS programmer.

Answer (score 2):

Because you want the caller of the macro to say which table they are going to select from, you have to switch to a dynamically generated SQL statement, which is only possible in a procedure.

A rough outline/example of what this may look like for you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE member_count(IN state CHAR(2))

--We have to tell it here that we will be returning a result set
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

BEGIN
    --Declare variables we will be using at the top

    --One variable for the sql string
    DECLARE my_sql VARCHAR(500);

    --And another for the cursor that we will open for the result set
    DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR WITH RETURN ONLY FOR my_statement;

    --Now we build our dynamically generated sql statement
    --we use two single quotes together to escape the quote character
    --(essentially we want a single quote in the SQL statement so we must
    --double it as it's already inside single quotes).
    SET my_sql = 'Select
        ''' || state1 || ''' as state,
         other_vars, etc
      FROM database.' || state_member || ';';

    --Now we "prepare" the "statement" from our string
    PREPARE my_statement FROM my_sql;

    --and we open the cursor. We don't close it because we want it returned.
    OPEN my_cursor;
END
```

That's going to need some spit and polish to get working as there is no `:state_member` variable declared or filled here, but it wasn't in your macro attempt either so that's probably out of scope for this question.

Comment: When I run this it says import style parameters found in query. Also, should the formatting of the code be off because of those single quotes? I have more in that 'pink color' than I have when I use this as a regular statement. Does that effect functionality?

Comment: Aslo, why does a single quote precede the select statement?

Comment: The single quote preceding the SELECT statement is because that SELECT statement is just a string. It's just a `VARCHAR(500)` variable that holds that SQL statement. We then execute the string stored in the variable `my_sql` in that `PREPARE` and `OPEN` statements that follow. This is what makes it "Dynamic" in the sense that Teradata has no idea what SQL it will be getting here since it's written only when the procedure is executed. As for the error you are hitting now, try putting the `IN` keyword before the variable name `state` in your `CREATE PROCEDURE` line. I will update.